# Correctly print custom CSS shape with transparent borders

Tags: html, css, firefox

When I try to print a custom CSS shape (say triangle) as pdf, the transparent areas get printed in black colour.
So what I see is not what I get (printed)!
example: http://cssdeck.com/labs/6jsbafpp

this what I get when printing the example page:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzzAm.png

Is there any workarounds to print exactly what I see?

Comment: did you used media all?

Comment: There must be something else. When I print this, I get exactly a red triangle, nothing else.

Comment: @OlafDietsche thanks that was helpful, the issue appears to be with firefox (25 on mac). unlike other browsers, firefox splits the triangle into 4 equal squares. On approach to fix the extra black triangles (as seen in attached pic) is to use "dotted transparent" instead of "solid transparent". However, the splitting lines still visible when zooming the pdf file.